# pandas filter date time: TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pandas, filter

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
    name    my_timestamp
------------------------------------------
0   a1      2016-07-28 09:27:07.536963-07:00
1   a2      2016-07-28 09:27:07.536963-07:00
2   a3      2016-08-15 13:05:54.924185-07:00
3   a4      2016-08-30 04:04:18.971667-07:00
4   a5      2016-03-22 14:36:22.999825-07:00
5   a6      2016-08-30 04:04:18.971667-07:00
```

I am trying to filter some rows in my pandas data frame like below:

```
import datetime
my_df[my_df.my_timestamp > datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 1)]
```

But get the following errors:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-35be746f191d> in <module>()
      1 import datetime
----> 2 my_df[my_df.my_timestamp > datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 1)]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.pyc in wrapper(self, other, axis)
    761                 other = np.asarray(other)
    762 
--> 763             res = na_op(values, other)
    764             if isscalar(res):
    765                 raise TypeError('Could not compare %s type with Series' %

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.pyc in na_op(x, y)
    681                     result = lib.vec_compare(x, y, op)
    682             else:
--> 683                 result = lib.scalar_compare(x, y, op)
    684         else:
    685 

pandas/lib.pyx in pandas.lib.scalar_compare (pandas/lib.c:14261)()

TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware date times
```

It seems to be the timezone issue. What would be the best way to ignore time-zone here? Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a sample of your dataframe? (and how it's constructed)

Comment: my_df[my_df.my_timestamp > pd.to_datetime("2016-07-01")]

Comment: @DennisGolomazov: sample data frame added. Thanks!

Comment: @piRSquared: I tried your suggestion, but still the same error. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all timestamps in the dataframe are in the same timezone:

```
tz_info = my_df.iloc[0].my_timestamp.tzinfo
my_df[my_df.my_timestamp > datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 1, tzinfo=tz_info)]
```

Comment: Works well. Thank you!

Comment: @Edamame glad it helps!